# Recommended directory structure for common ruby (non rails) modules and classes used by multiple projects

Tags: ruby, directory-structure

After spending too much time writing bad code in Ruby I decided to try to do it right.  I found here and in other places good guides for the directory structure of a single ruby project (not rails).
I am now interested in the situation where I have some modules and classes that are used by several projects.  I don't want to have to duplicate those modules in the lib folder of each project.

So, my beginner's question is: what is the best way to setup a directory structure that would accomodate those classes and modules that are reused by multiple projects.
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If it's something used by multiple projects, put it all together, give it a name and make a gem out of it: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Comment: @NickVeys: Your comment could have been posted as an answer, I fully agree.

Comment: @NickVeys Thank you for the suggestion.  Looks good.  I take this as the answer to my question.